# Trying to detect palm lines with OpenCv in Kotlin

Tags: python, android, kotlin, opencv

Now a days I am trying to make an app to detect a palm line with help of openCV and Kotlin. I found a lot of code using opencv and python in stackoverflow but when I try to run that code in kotlin I am not getting any useful output.

So I need a support from you guys in my project to detect palm lines.

What I have done in code

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        OpenCVLoader.initDebug()

        val tv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.open)
        imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)

        tv.setOnClickListener {
            openGallery()
        }
    }

    private fun openGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedImage = data?.data

            ProcessImageTask().execute(selectedImage)
        }
    }

    private fun getBitmapFromUri(uri: Uri?): Bitmap {
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri!!)
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
    }

    private fun processImageWithOpenCV(originalBitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        // Convert the Bitmap to a Mat
        val palmMat = Mat()
        Utils.bitmapToMat(originalBitmap, palmMat)

        // Convert the image to grayscale
        val gray = Mat()
        Imgproc.cvtColor(palmMat, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        // Apply Gaussian Blur
        val kernelSize = 5
        val blurGray = Mat()
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, blurGray, org.opencv.core.Size(kernelSize.toDouble(), kernelSize.toDouble()), 0.0)

        // Apply Canny edge detection
        val lowThreshold = 50.0
        val highThreshold = 150.0
        val edges = Mat()
        Imgproc.Canny(blurGray, edges, lowThreshold, highThreshold)

        // Run Hough on edge-detected image
        val rho = 1.0
        val theta = Math.PI / 180.0
        val threshold = 15
        val minLineLength = 50.0
        val maxLineGap = 20.0
        val lineImage = Mat.zeros(edges.rows(), edges.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3) // Change type to CV_8UC3
        val lines = MatOfFloat6()
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(edges, lines, rho, theta, threshold.toInt(), minLineLength, maxLineGap)

// Draw lines on the lineImage
        val linesArray = lines.toArray()
        for (i in 0 until linesArray.size / 4) {
            val x1 = linesArray[4 * i].toDouble()
            val y1 = linesArray[4 * i + 1].toDouble()
            val x2 = linesArray[4 * i + 2].toDouble()
            val y2 = linesArray[4 * i + 3].toDouble()

            Imgproc.line(
                lineImage,
                Point(x1, y1),
                Point(x2, y2),
                Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                5
            )
        }

// Add weighted combination of the original image and the image with detected lines
        val linesEdges = Mat()
        Core.addWeighted(palmMat, 0.8, lineImage, 1.0, 0.0, linesEdges)

        // Convert the result back to Bitmap
        val processedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(linesEdges.cols(), linesEdges.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        Utils.matToBitmap(linesEdges, processedBitmap)

        // Display the processed image
        imageView.setImageBitmap(processedBitmap)

        return processedBitmap
    }

    private inner class ProcessImageTask : AsyncTask<Uri?, Void, Bitmap?>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Uri?): Bitmap? {
            val selectedImage = params[0]
            return if (selectedImage != null) {
                val bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImage)
                processImageWithOpenCV(bitmap)
            } else {
                null
            }
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)

            if (result != null) {
                // Optionally, save the processed image to the gallery
                saveImageToGallery(result, "ProcessedWithLines")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun saveImageToGallery(bitmap: Bitmap, displayName: String) {
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "$displayName.jpg")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        }

        val contentResolver = contentResolver
        val uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

        uri?.let {
            val outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(it)
            if (outputStream != null) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
            }
            outputStream?.close()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I know today we have a AI tool to provide a example of code but Developers will be always developers.

Thanks in advance!!